# Verificar existência de um arquivo

Tags: java, url, inputstream

Dada uma url de um arquivo:

```
URL pomUrl = new URL("https://gitlab/grupo/projeto/blob/develop/pom.xml");
```

Como posso verificar a existência de um arquivo irmão a esse?

Algo do tipo:

```
public boolean temIrmao(String pomUrl) {
    if (pomUrl.contains("index.html") return true
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use o método exists()

Comment: Gabriel, o que você quer dizer com 'arquivo irmão'? Seriam outros arquivos no mesmo diretório?

Comment: @JoelLobo exatamente!

Answer (score 0):

Em minhas pesquisas, observei que há a seguinte possibilidade:

```
File arquivo = new File("CAMINHO DO ARQUIVO.EXTENSÃO");
if(arquivo.exists()){
    //O ARQUIVO EXISTE - RETORNA TRUE
}else{
    //O ARQUIVO NÃO EXISTE  - CASO RETORNE FALSE
}
```

Você pode aprimorar o código para sua necessidade substituindo o caminho e dentro do if, verificando se há o mesmo arquivo com o mesmo nome e extensão e/ou url.